# Getting the location of a tweet and regarding hot new things about twitter API

Tags: api, twitter, geolocation

Guys!! How can I get the location of a tweet i.e. where it originated from? I'm a new web  developer so I need some hot new topics which are cool to work upon in the twitter api. Suggest me some real good topics. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every tweet delivered by the Twitter API has a geo_lat and geo_long value. Unfortunately, less than 0.5% of tweets have that filled in on average. Very few people have Twitter include their phone GPS data in a tweet.